# Css Grid column's Stacking on top of each other

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I know my HTML and CSS are a bit too much expand, but when I combine things it has worse errors. My code is below all I need is the last bar to fit like the other one. I have tried to change the padding and margins of that row as well as completely redoing my grid.

```css
#grid {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#topbar {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: white;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  display: grid;
}

#topbar #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

#topbar #img {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

/* For each lan div id use #then div name to style */

#plot1 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: #cdcdcb;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
}

#plot1 #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #deded8;
}

#plot1 #img {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#plot1 #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#plot1 #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: right;
}

#plot1 #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#plot1 #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

#last {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: #cdcdcb;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  display: grid;
}

#last #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #deded8;
}

#last #img {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#last #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#last #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: right;
}

#last #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#last #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
          <div id="topbar">
            <div id="pad1">
            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>Property</p>
            </div>
            <div id="li">
              <p>Location &amp; Information</p>
            </div>
            <div id="acre">
              <p>Acareage</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf">
              <p>PDF</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pad2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--For each piece of land add a div with its name then set grid potition in css sheet.-->
          <div id="plot1">
            <div id="pad1">
            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>Property</p>
            </div>
            <div id="li">
              <p>Location &amp; Information</p>
            </div>
            <div id="acre">
              <p>Acareage</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf">
              <p>PDF</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pad2">
            </div
          </div>
          <div id="last">
            <div id="pad1">

            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>hello</p>  
            </div>
            <div id="li">

            </div>
            <div id="acre">

            </div>
            <div id="pdf">

            </div>
            <div id="pad2">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="foot">
          <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Greater Texas Land Resources LP &amp;<a href="mailto:coding.matthew.horton@gmail.com"> Design</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The last row is messed up a am trying to copy the row before it so it creates a chart type thing that can hold infromation

Comment: The first row is supposed to be different

Answer (score 2):

you did not properly close a `div` tag.*(`#pad2` not properly closed )*

```
     <div id="pad2">
        </div
      </div>
      <div id="last">
        <div id="pad1">
```

beside, `id` **can only be used once**, use `class` instead when you need to apply same style a few times.

```css
#grid {
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#topbar {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: white;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  display: grid;
}

#topbar #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

#topbar #img {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#topbar #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

/* For each lan div id use #then div name to style */

#plot1 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: #cdcdcb;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  display: grid;
}

#plot1 #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #deded8;
}

#plot1 #img {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#plot1 #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#plot1 #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: right;
}

#plot1 #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#plot1 #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}

#last {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(20, 1fr);
  background-color: #cdcdcb;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  display: grid;
}

#last #pad1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: #deded8;
}

#last #img {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#last #li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 5 / 15;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: left;
}

#last #acre {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 15 / 17;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: right;
}

#last #pdf {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  grid-column: 17 / 19;
  color: rgb(179, 9, 50);
  text-align: center;
}

#last #pad2 {
  grid-column: 19 / 21;
  background-color: #e0e0df;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
          <div id="topbar">
            <div id="pad1">
            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>Property</p>
            </div>
            <div id="li">
              <p>Location &amp; Information</p>
            </div>
            <div id="acre">
              <p>Acareage</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf">
              <p>PDF</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pad2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--For each piece of land add a div with its name then set grid potition in css sheet.-->
          <div id="plot1">
            <div id="pad1">
            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>Property</p>
            </div>
            <div id="li">
              <p>Location &amp; Information</p>
            </div>
            <div id="acre">
              <p>Acareage</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf">
              <p>PDF</p>
            </div>
            <div id="pad2">
            </div><!--- here was the syntax typo -->
          </div>
          <div id="last">
            <div id="pad1">

            </div>
            <div id="img">
              <p>hello</p>  
            </div>
            <div id="li">

            </div>
            <div id="acre">

            </div>
            <div id="pdf">

            </div>
            <div id="pad2">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="foot">
          <p>Copyright &copy; 2017 Greater Texas Land Resources LP &amp;<a href="mailto:coding.matthew.horton@gmail.com"> Design</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who double-checked there are no html errors, stacking can occur because of `grid-area`. Assigning a `grid-area` locks the element to the first cell that `grid-template-areas` defines for it.

The following causes stacking:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
  border: 2px solid seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">1,1</div>
  <div class="right">1,2</div>
  <div class="left">2,1</div>
  <div class="right">2,2</div>
  <div class="left">3,1</div>
  <div class="right">3,2</div>
</div>
```

The same example, without the `grid-area` assignments fixes the issue:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: .5em;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  /* This should also be taken out since it serves no purpose anymore.
     Leaving it here to show the container property has no bearing on repeats by itself.
     Only when the contents use the assignments */
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
}

.left {
  /*grid-area: left;*/
  border: 2px solid skyblue;
}

.right {
  /*grid-area: right;*/
  border: 2px solid seagreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left">1,1</div>
  <div class="right">1,2</div>
  <div class="left">2,1</div>
  <div class="right">2,2</div>
  <div class="left">3,1</div>
  <div class="right">3,2</div>
</div>
```

For a simple layout like this, all the various grid-row settings for the container I played around with from other posts were completely unnecessary:

- `grid-auto-rows: auto;`
- `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto);`
- `grid-auto-flow: column;`

`display: grid` automatically defaults to repeating rows, unless you specifically define `grid-template-areas` and assign `grid-area` to the lock the contents into place.